# How to check the column with element id and class?

Tags: jquery

I am working on my jquery code for my keyboard control. I need some help with the if statement, I am still trying to find out how to check on the column value 2 with the currentdivwidth size 250 while checking with the element id '.row2' and the class 'span0hr' at the same time when the column value 2 with the size 250 before doing something.

I tried this:

```
if (current_row == 2 && currentdivwidth[0] == 250) {
    alert("passed");
    if (current_row == 2 && ($('.span0hr').hasClass('row2'))) {
        alert("fix this 1");
    } else if (current_row == 2 && ($('.row2').hasClass('span1hrfor30mins'))) {
        alert("fix this 2");
    }
}
```

I can get pass when the column value is 2 with the size 250, but i can't get pass when the column value is 2 with the size 250 at the same time checking with the element id '.row2' and the class 'span0hr'.

Do you know how i can check on the element id '.row2' and the class 'span0hr' at the same time when the column value is 2 with the size 250?

I have done this at the other day, but i have lost my work due to overwritten.

Comment: could use your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID selector is preceded by #.
The . is used to precede a class name on the selector.

ie.:

```
if ($("#row2").hasClass("theClassYouWant"))
    // do something
```

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptvtD/

Comment: do i have to use something like this? if ($("#row2").hasClass('span1hrfor30mins'))

Comment: Can you post the HTML bits?

Comment: you can take a look at my website: http://testbox.elementfx.com/test.php. sorry i couldn't post the html because the code is too large.

Comment: I've updated the answer again. It's different from your code, but the same behavior.

Comment: oh i got it now thank you very much for your help which it much appreicated. problem solved!